# react: remove button outline on focus without css

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

i want to remove the outline of the button without using a css file. I know it could be done in css file buy having `button:focus {outline:0;}`, but i don't want to use a css file. I am writing my style as a `const style={button:{...}}` and link it like this `<button style={style.button}></button>`. Is it possible to make it like this?

Comment: Yes that is how you could do an inline style. Did you try it? should be something like `<button style={{outline: 0}}>` or define `const style={button: {outline: 0}}` and then use like you have in your answer

Comment: Why dont you want to use css here though?

Comment: sometimes it overrides some other buttons i don't want to add to them the same styling and it get over heading for me

Comment: you should have a global reset css that removes the outline on all buttons